# Can not find the Mi band Xiaomi blurtooth protocol

Tags: bluetooth

I am having a problem finding the Mi band bluetooth protocol, I have searched all over the internet but there are no information about it.

Is there anyone out there that could give me some info on the Mi band bluetooth protocol?

I want to enable and disble the vibrator motor, what are the bluetooth registers which I have to write to?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This links might help you, if my answer does not fit your question(s)
http://changy-.github.io/articles/xiao-mi-band-protocol-analyze.html
https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/accessories/xiaomi-mi-band-data-extraction-t3019156

Here you can find the following characteristics:

```
0xff05, CONTROL_POINT
Stop motor vibrate --> write 19


0xff0b, STATISTICS
Byte[0] --> wake (ms)
Byte[1] --> vibrate (ms)
Byte[2] --> light (ms)
Byte[3] --> conn (s)
Byte[4] --> adv (s)

0xff0d, TEST
Write 2 to Characteristic 0xFF0D (TEST).
```

Your Mi Band will do crazy things (LED flashing,vibrate)

```
Write 1 to Characteristic 0xFF0D (TEST) --> disconnect
```

Comment: OK thank you I will check these out and give you feedback.